# How to open an attachment based on the date picker

Tags: attachments, datepicker

I am creating an E-Paper kind of functionality in WordPress where the user will have to select a date from the date picker and the corresponding attachment will open. I looked all around but didn't find any suitable plugin or code.

Now, I am aware that the name or some metadata needs to match the date so that it is fetched easily. I just want to know the backend of this process. How should I go about saving the date from date picker and fetch the corresponding attachment (preferably PDF) ?

This type of functionality is used in almost all of publication sites and I want to know if it can be implemented in WordPress.

Comment: "is used in almost all of publication sites" If this is true then an example would be easy to come by, and might help clarify what you're trying to do. I don't quite understand from the question.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://epaper.bhaskar.com/). Here, the newspapers are fetched using a dropdown consisting of cities. How can I do the same thing with date picker?

Answer (score 0):

I did it! In the end, I used the standard $_REQUEST and $_GET to store and fetch the value in the date-picker instead of all the fancy hooks and filters.

The only thing I am not able to fathom out is the deal with input type-button. It was not storing the value in $_REQUEST. But when I used input type-text, it was all too easy. I don't understand what input type-button is for if it cannot even store a value.
If someone can explain it to me, it would be awesome!